# How to Refresh Custom Toolbar in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a custom toolbar I made here is the code:

```
public BoloToolbar()
            : base()
    {
        Init();
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        ClientViewModel Client = new ClientViewModel();

        if (Client.IsLogged == "true")
        {          
            this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem ("Twój Koszyk", "Images/cart.png", ()  =>
            {
                Navigation.PushAsync(new CartPage());
            }));

            this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("Moje Zamówienia", null, () =>
            {
                Navigation.PushAsync(new Zamowienia());
            }, ToolbarItemOrder.Secondary, priority:0));


            this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("Mój Profil", null, () =>
            {
                Navigation.PushAsync(new Profile());
            }, ToolbarItemOrder.Secondary, priority: 0));

            this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("Ustawienia", null, () =>
            {
            }, ToolbarItemOrder.Secondary, priority: 0));

            this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("Kontakt", null, () =>
            {
                Navigation.PushAsync(new Kontakt());
            }, ToolbarItemOrder.Secondary, priority: 0));

            this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("Wyloguj", null, () =>
            {
                //Navigation.PushAsync(new Kontakt());
                Application.Current.Properties["isLogged"] = "false";
                Application.Current.Properties["userId"] = "";
                DisplayAlert("Logout", "Wylogowano Pomyślnie", "OK");
            }, ToolbarItemOrder.Secondary, priority: 0));

        } else
        {
            this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("Zaloguj", null, () =>
            {
                Navigation.PushAsync(new LogRegister());
            }, ToolbarItemOrder.Secondary, priority: 0));

            this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("Utwórz Konto", null, () =>
            {
                Navigation.PushAsync(new RegisterAccount());
            }, ToolbarItemOrder.Secondary, priority: 0));
        }
```

And lets say I start the app and log in etc. whenever I come back to the page where I have toolbar (lets say Main Page) the toolbar doesnt refresh (its not re-checking if u are actually logged)

I know there is INotifyPropertyChanged for viewmodels, is there something similar for custom toolbars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the constructor being only called once move this code in the `OnAppearing` method and it should work.

```
public BoloToolbar(): base()
    {

    }
protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        Init();
    }
    private void Init()
    {
        ClientViewModel Client = new ClientViewModel();

        if (Client.IsLogged == "true")
        {          
            this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem ("Twój Koszyk", "Images/cart.png", ()  =>
            {
                Navigation.PushAsync(new CartPage());
            }));

            this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("Moje Zamówienia", null, () =>
            {
                Navigation.PushAsync(new Zamowienia());
            }, ToolbarItemOrder.Secondary, priority:0));


            this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("Mój Profil", null, () =>
            {
                Navigation.PushAsync(new Profile());
            }, ToolbarItemOrder.Secondary, priority: 0));

            this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("Ustawienia", null, () =>
            {
            }, ToolbarItemOrder.Secondary, priority: 0));

            this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("Kontakt", null, () =>
            {
                Navigation.PushAsync(new Kontakt());
            }, ToolbarItemOrder.Secondary, priority: 0));

            this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("Wyloguj", null, () =>
            {
                //Navigation.PushAsync(new Kontakt());
                Application.Current.Properties["isLogged"] = "false";
                Application.Current.Properties["userId"] = "";
                DisplayAlert("Logout", "Wylogowano Pomyślnie", "OK");
            }, ToolbarItemOrder.Secondary, priority: 0));

        } else
        {
            this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("Zaloguj", null, () =>
            {
                Navigation.PushAsync(new LogRegister());
            }, ToolbarItemOrder.Secondary, priority: 0));

            this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("Utwórz Konto", null, () =>
            {
                Navigation.PushAsync(new RegisterAccount());
            }, ToolbarItemOrder.Secondary, priority: 0));
        }
```

Comment: it doesnt work, when I go to another page and come back the toolbar "doubles itself" there are options x 2 then and so on and so on.. also instead of choosing between "2" options now two appear (the toolbar inside in -true and else )

How do I make it dissaear if "else shows" up?

Comment: Umm I did not understand what you are saying can you please elaborate

Comment: nvm, I had to add ToolbarItems.Clear() before Init() (so it can remove existing ones and replace with the new values - Thank you!

Comment: Sure no problem!